# column_types is nil in Rails 4.0.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I'm attempting to upgrade Rails from 4.0.0 to 4.0.2, but there's a change that was introduced in 4.0.1 that's breaking my application.

Here's the error I'm seeing:

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb:86:in `block in read_attribute'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb:84:in `fetch'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb:84:in `read_attribute'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb:59:in `__temp__6696273747f5e616d656'
app/models/player.rb:20:in `short_name'
```

Here's my application code where the stack trace starts:

```
# app/models/player.rb
def short_name
  self.class.where(first_name: first_name).where('id != ?', id).exists? ? name : first_name
end
```

Here's the diff (and [the commit on Rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/975c9c9d4498a4b4a00de713e932abe3299a4007)) that appears to be the problem:

```
diff -r activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb

[snip]

80,86c85,92
<           column = @columns_hash.fetch(name) {
<             return @attributes.fetch(name) {
<               if name == 'id' && self.class.primary_key != name
<                 read_attribute(self.class.primary_key)
<               end
<             }
<           }
---
>           column = @column_types_override[name] if @column_types_override
>           column ||= @column_types[name]
> 
>           return @attributes.fetch(name) {
>             if name == 'id' && self.class.primary_key != name
>               read_attribute(self.class.primary_key)
>             end
>           } unless column
```

According to the stack trace, `@column_types` is nil, and I can't figure out why.

I don't have this problem from the console, only when I'm running in a server, either Thin via `rails s` (development environment) or Unicorn via `foreman start` (production environment). It also fails when I deploy to staging on Heroku. I have tests covering this method too, and they pass.

Does anyone know where `@column_types` is supposed to be set and why it's nil in this case?

Comment: Are you using Shopify?

Comment: @PeterAlfvin Nope. I'm using Dalli and Memcachier, and this method is normally cached, but even when I take out the caching (as in the code snippet I posted), I still get the failure.

Comment: I don't know if it's related, but I found https://github.com/Shopify/identity_cache/pull/108

Comment: Did you open an issue on GitHub? Sounds like a bug to me.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin It definitely looks like the same bug bit them. I put that same line directly into my `short_name` method and everything started working again.

Comment: @phoet I haven't yet, but it does look like a bug. Just need a minimal test case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just hit this too - you'll need to update the `protected_attributes` gem to version 1.0.5.

There's a bit more info here: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/13246

---

**Edit from OP:** You may only need to flush your cache, which is mentioned in that thread:

```
Rails.cache.clear
```

Comment: Thank you! I just managed to figure it out right before I refreshed this question and saw your answer. I ended up just flushing my caches, which was no big deal for this application.