# Error undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass in devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working on `rails 4`

**gemfile:**

`gem "devise", "~> 3.2.2"`

**cmd:**

`> rails g devise:install`

`> rails g devise authorize`

`> rake db:migrate`

**Error:**

```
C:\Sites\scroll>rake db:migrate
==  DeviseCreateAuthorizes: migrating    =========================================
 -- create_table(:authorizes)
 -> 0.1676s
-- add_index(:authorizes, :email, {:unique=>true})
-> 0.0644s
-- add_index(:authorizes, :reset_password_token, {:unique=>true})
-> 0.0418s
==  DeviseCreateAuthorizes: migrated (0.2798s) ================================

rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

 undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

**Including --trace**

```
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

undefined method `[]' for   nil:NilClassF:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/
2.0.0/gems/activerecord-  4.0.2/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb:86:in`block in read_attribute'
F:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord- 4.0.2/lib/acti
ve_record/attribute_methods/read.rb:84:in `fetch'
F:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb:84:in `read_attribute'
F:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-  4.0.2/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:243:in `block in attributes'
F:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-  4.0.2/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:242:in `each'
F:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:242:in `each_with_object'
F:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:242:in `attributes'
F:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:84:in`keys_for_partial_write'
F:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:78:in `create_record'

`<top (required)>'
F:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/bin/rake:23:in `load'
F:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

**migration:**

```
  class DeviseCreateAuthorizes < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
    create_table(:authorizes) do |t|
  ## Database authenticatable
  t.string :email,              :null => false, :default => ""
  t.string :encrypted_password, :null => false, :default => ""

  ## Recoverable
  t.string   :reset_password_token
  t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

  ## Rememberable
  t.datetime :remember_created_at

  ## Trackable
  t.integer  :sign_in_count, :default => 0, :null => false
  t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
  t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
  t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
  t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

  ## Confirmable
  # t.string   :confirmation_token
  # t.datetime :confirmed_at
  # t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
  # t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

  ## Lockable
  # t.integer  :failed_attempts, :default => 0, :null => false # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
  # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
  # t.datetime :locked_at


  t.timestamps
end

add_index :authorizes, :email,                :unique => true
add_index :authorizes, :reset_password_token, :unique => true

 end
end
```

**what is going wrong**

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like that migration ran fine.  Can you run with `--trace?` and add the results to your question?

Comment: i have edited do check

Comment: Might help to see the contents of your migrations as well.

Comment: i have included migration contents

Comment: This error is being referenced in a couple of posts.  Maybe they are related:  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20596842/column-types-is-nil-in-rails-4-0-1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21297934/undefined-method-for-nilnilclass-for-rails-model-on-new

Comment: they are not..mine is different, i saw many

Comment: Did the migration happen? If it added indexes, it seems to have run, but then come back with the error?